# youtube_explode_dart package has wrong documentation

Tags: flutter, dart, package, project, documentation

I am trying to use flutter `youtube_explode_dart` package but I am facing some errors mainly two

1. with `video.property`

Code:-

```
 var video = yt.videos.get('https://youtube.com/watch?v=Dpp1sIL1m5Q');
 var title = video.title; // Error in this line
```

2. with `streamManifest`

   Code:-

   ```
    // Error saying streamManifest is not defined
    var streamInfo = streamManifest.muxed.withHigestVideoQuality();
   ```

Link to the documentation code :- https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_explode_dart

If anyone has used the package or knows the fix PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

use
manifest=yt.videos.streamsClient.getManifest(url);
after getting manifest then
var streamInfo = manifest.muxed.withHigestVideoQuality();
then use this hopefully your error will be solved please let me know if solved